Prove that the derivative of the mollification approaches the strong $L^p$ derivative
Let $g \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $\int_\mathbb{R} g dx = 1$. Suppose that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}$ has a strong $L^p$ derivative, i.e. there is some $h$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{y \to 0} \Vert \frac{f(x+y) - f(x)}{y} - h(x) \Vert_p = 0$.
We know that $f * g_t \to f$ in the $L^p$ norm. However, I have also read that $(f * g_t)'(x) \to h(x)$, where $h(x)$ is the strong $L^p$ norm. I am trying to manipulate the definition of $h(x)$ to see that this indeed is the case but I am having a hard time. I know that $(f*g_t)'(x) = (f*g_t')(x)$. It suffices to show that for any given $\epsilon > 0$, for all sufficiently small $t > 0$ and $y$ we have $\Vert (f * g_t')(x) - \frac{f(x+y) - f(x)}{y} \Vert_p$. It seems like the Holder's inequality may be helpful, but I wasn't getting to my goal. I have read here and there in math stack exchange, and they were talking about weak derivative. How does this relate?

It's probably easiest to just show that $h$ is the distributional derivative of $f$, and then use $(f * g)' = (f' * g)$.
